# bitwise left shift and | operations in makefile

Tags: makefile

I need to do left shift and OR operations in makefile. Something like below:

```
a = $(b) << 2 | 0x1
```

…where is `b` is a numeric value read using a `$(shell )` command in a makefile.

I tried the following but it didn't help.

```
a = $(shell echo $(b) << 2 | bc)
```

I mean `a` as got value of `b` but not the shifted value after running the script.

Answer (score 2):

The version of `bc` I have access to doesn't support bitwise operations, so it seems to be barking up the wrong tree.  The default shell `gnumake` uses is `/bin/sh` but you can make it use bash instead and then access bash's bitwise operators directly:

```
SHELL=bash

a := $(( $(b) << 2 | 1 ))
```

Thanks to @EtanReisner for pointing out that this will cause that entire string to be stored in the variable `a` which would then be evaluated if you use it in a recipe. If you want the computed value stored directly in a you still need to get the shell to evaluate it:

```
a := $(shell echo "$$(( $(b) << 2 | 1 ))" )
```

Comment: That stores the literal string `$(( ## << 2 | 1 ))` in the variable `a`. That then needs to be used in a recipe context for the shell to evaluate it. You need `$(shell)` there to evaluate it directly.

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't think that's true. If you put a `$(shell)` around it the shell will try to evaluate the result of the computation (i.e. a number).

Comment: You'll need to echo the result, that's true `a:=$(shell echo "$$(( $(b) << 2 | 1 ))")`. By try sticking `$(info a: $a)` at the end of your snippet and running it through GNU make and see what you get as output and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks, I've been educated. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks "Turn" for the response.

Comment: Thanks Turn and Etanreisner, but the solution didn't worked for me.

Comment: @siri Can you elaborate? What happens?

Comment: Thanks Turn and Etanreisner, but the solution didn't worked for me. Can you please help me to know where i am going wrong ? or any alternative way to perform left shift and | operations ?

Comment: all i can say is the expression doesn't result in a value and "a" still is empty.

Comment: Are you running gnumake? Can you use Etan's suggestion of putting `$(info a: $a)` somewhere in your makefile?

Comment: I used below lines in my make file

Comment: i used below lines in my make file  "prav := $(shell echo "$$(4 << 2 | 1)")
$(info prav: $prav)" and below is the output with $(info prav:$prav) command -- "prav: rav"

Comment: You need to use parenthesis around a variable with more than one character: `$(prav)`.

Comment: HI Turn, i used these lines prav := $(shell echo "$$(4 << 2 | 1)")
$(info prav: $(prav)) and output is just "prav:".....I am a beginner in makefile and sorry for dumb answers.

Comment: and i am using /bin/sh.

Comment: GNU Make 3.81 is output of "make -ver"

Comment: Did you use the `SHELL=bash` (or perhaps `SHELL=/bin/bash`) line at the top of your Makefile?

Comment: yes. tried SHELL=/bin/bash at top of make file but no change.

Comment: Look at what you typed again and compare it to what is in my answer above. You don't have enough ('s.

Comment: my bad. i regret for the mistake. yes now it works for me.

Comment: sure turn. My bad as instead of using copy paste i started typing u'r answer in my make file and lost so much time. As i said, i am a beginner and will accept everything and experiment.